# How can I loop through an object and get the index of each element and store it in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what I have tried so far but I am only getting 1 value in return.

```
Object.keys(yelpResults).map((key) => {
  return setRestaurantIndexes(restaurantIndexes.concat(key));
});
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you want the end result to be an array of indexes? Am I reading it correctly? "...get the index of each element and store it in an array". So your resultant array will look something like this: [1,2,3,4,5]? Or did you mean you want to get the "key" of each element and store it in an array?

Answer (score -1):

you can refer this example if it helps.
Map function can be executed on array , so first we need to convert object into array and then execute operation on it.

```
const details={
  name:'John',
  lName:'lee',
  country:'US'
}

const getIndex = Object.keys(details).map((item , i)=>{
  return i;  
});

console.log(getIndex);
```

Comment: you don't have to push in an array. 
```const getIndex = Object.keys(details).map((item, index) => index);```

you will get array of indexes in getIndex

Answer (score -1):

The function `Object.keys` alone do the trick, it returns an array with the names of the properties and methods of an object.

```js
const data = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 50,
  country: 'NZ'
}

const propertyNames = Object.keys(data)

console.log(propertyNames);
// prints: ['name', 'age', 'country']
```

Answer (score -1):

- First make your object.

  ```
  const result = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];
  ```
- Then declare an array where you will save your index values

  ```
  let newArray = []
  ```
- Then loop through the object created at step 1.

  ```
  //loop the results

  for(var i=0, l=result.length; i < l; i++){

    //push the object's index to the array  

    newArray.push(i);
  }
  ```
- Console Log your new array with index values saved in it.

  ```
  console.log(newArray);
  ```

Comment: `const result = ["Apple", "Orange", "Plum"];` is not an object, it's an array.